# In Rails, can the secret_key_base be updated without losing previously signed data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies

In Rails 4.x the `secret_key_base` is used to sign the session cookie and also any other signed cookies created by calling `cookies.signed`.

I'd like to update/cycle/roll this `secret_key_base`, but without losing access to all of the previously signed cookies (I don't mind losing the sessions). Is it possible to do this?

Ideally I'd like something like:

1. Add new `secret_key_base`.
2. Use both the old and new `secret_key_base`'s alongside each other over a period of time, so that cookies signed using the older key can be re-signed with the newer key.
3. Remove the old `secret_key_base`.

I know there was similar functionality for upgrading from using a `secret_token` to a `secret_key_base`. Is there a way to achieve this using Rails?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by overwriting some of the methods like `encrypted` and `signed` in the cookies middleware to first try to read the cookies with your old `secret_key_base`. if it succeeds then you can upgrade them to new one. Eventually all old cookies will be upgraded to new ones and then you can just remove your custom patches. Take a look at

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8350925bec434168f56b4fae22b5298cb4a83c41/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb

also checkout how message verifier is working here.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8350925bec434168f56b4fae22b5298cb4a83c41/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb#L251

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can tackle it in different way.
Keep the old secret_key for now and make a temporary table where you can store all the cookie data mapped to a particular user. Can use redis for this as well. When you are quite sure that all the existing cookie data has been received, you can change the secret_key. This should invalidate all the cookie data. Now whenever cookies are received, you can first check if that data exists for the user and set the cookie accordingly and remove the entry from the temporary table/key_store. Once your temporary table is empty, you can remove the mechanism altogether

Comment: How would I know which particular user it is? I cannot assume that the visitor is logged in. Even if we generated a unique identifier for each visitor, it would seem that we'd have to either store it in either an unsigned cookie (making it trivial to get someone else's cookie data) or another signed cookie (back to where we started).